# Android : how to adjust custom list views?

Tags: android, xml, listview, custom-lists

I want to display one `ImageView`, 2 `TextViews` and one `Rating Bar` in one node in custom list adapter but it crop it when I run the code here is the xml code of custom list 
  [Here is the picture of list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XuaX.png)

**custom_list.xml**

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TableRow>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_column="2" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/tv_deal"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:text="deals" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RatingBar android:id="@+id/rb_rating"
        android:layout_column="2" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Any reasons why you use `TableLayout` instead `RelativeLayout` ? ... also it seems like the problem is not here but in layout where you have a listview

Comment: Is Relative Layout works like this in custom layout ?

Comment: yes it works. Post your Listview or Recyclerview layout

Comment: comment about RelativeLayout was off-topic (it more about good practices) i had edited the comment and added what could be the problem

Comment: Use Relative Layout to maker your Listview Item XML. That is more efficient   .

Comment: the problem is in width of your ListView. It is in the file, where you declare a ListView.

Comment: @VladMatvienko Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below XML for your ListView Item :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_deal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img"
        android:text="deals"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rb_rating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_deal" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes you were right `RealtiveLayout` is more efficient than table Layout